# How to save a file in MapR HDFS using Ruby

Tags: ruby, hadoop, hdfs, mapr

Is there a way to save a file in HDFS using MapR distribution of Hadoop from Ruby?

Apparently, there's a Thrift API called `thriftfs` that makes it possible to communicate with HDFS from clients but looks like it is not bundled with MapR.

Comment: did you consider using JRuby?

Comment: I suggested doing that but due to the fact that our app might depend on some MRI-only gems we can not adopt JRuby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also answered this question at http://answers.mapr.com/questions/1525/how-to-run-thriftfs-from-mapr?page=1#1528

The basic idea is that languages like Ruby don't need language specific bindings to get access to the file system of a MapR cluster.  Instead, all you need to do is mount the cluster as an NFS file system and you are good to go with any file access that you can dream up.  This makes scripting in a Hadoop environment vastly easier.